# reading a line, tokenizing and assigning to struct in C

Tags: c, string

`line` is fgets'd, and running in a `while` loop with counter `n`,  `d` is a struct with 2 char arrays, `p` and `q`. Basically, in a few words, I want to read a line, separate it into 2 strings, one up until the first space, and the other with the rest of the line. I clean up afterwards (`\n` from the file becomes \'0'). The code works, but is there a more idiomatic way to do this? What errors am I running into "unknowingly"?

```
    size_t spc = strcspn(line," ");
    strncpy(d[n].p, line, spc);
    d[n].p[spc+1]='\0';
    size_t l = strlen(line)-spc;
    strncpy(d[n].q, line+spc+1, l);
    char* nl = strchr(d[n].q, '\n');
    if(nl){
      *nl='\0';
    }
    n++;
```

**EDIT**: `q` may contain spaces.

Thanks.

Comment: `strcspn` and `strlen` return `size_t`, not `int`. Using the wrong type here is harmless 99% of the time but it's a bad habit because every once in a while it can result in vulnerabilities.

Comment: @R: Fixed. And "5" more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write very nearly the code you have.  Some tweaks:

- You're not getting anything out of `strncpy` here, use `memcpy`.
- You're not getting anything out of `strcspn` either, use `strchr`.
- Avoid scanning parts of the string twice.

So:

```
char *spc = strchr(line, ' ');
memcpy(d[n].p, line, spc - line);
d[n].p[spc - line] = '\0';

spc++;
char *end = strchr(spc, '\n');
if (end)
{
    memcpy(d[n].q, spc, end - spc);
    d[n].q[end - spc] = '\0';
} 
else 
    strcpy(d[n].q, spc);

n++;
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with pure pointer arithmetic only. Assuming `line` contains the current line:

```
char *p = line;
char *part1, *part2;

while (*p && *p != ' ') {
  p++;
}

if (*p == ' ') {
  *p++ = '\0';
  part1 = strdup(line);
  part2 = strdup(p);

  if (!part1 || !part2) {
    /* insufficient memory */
  }
} else {
  /* line doesn't contain a space */
}
```

Basically you scan the string till the first occurrence of a space, then replace the space with a null character to indicate the end of the first part (`strdup` needs to know where to stop), and advance the pointer by one to get the rest of the string.

To make the code look even cleaner but with the overhead of calling a function, you could use `strchr()` instead of the `while` loop:

```
char *p = strchr(line, ' ');
char *part1, *part2;

if (p) {
  *p++ = '\0';
  part1 = strdup(line);
  part2 = strdup(p);
}
```

Comment: strdup is not c standard, what do you do if words breaks with '\t' and other whitespaces

Comment: `strpbrk(line, " \t")` could be used instead, and `strdup` is a part of the POSIX standard which makes it widely supported.

Answer (score 1):

You could always use:

```
sscanf(line, "%s %s", d[n].p, d[n].q);
```

Assuming the stuff you want to put into p and q does not contain spaces, and that p and q is guaranteed to be large enough to hold the tokens including zero-termination.

The scanf function is dangerous, but very useful when used correctly.

Comment: Then check the scanf manpage you need a slightly more elaborate pattern to match instead of the last %s.

Comment: space in formatstring will be ignored, "%s %s" is equivalent to "%s%s"

Answer (score 1):

```
scanf("%s %[^\n]", d[n].p, d[n].q);
```

The `%[...]` directive is like `%s`, but instead of matching non-whitespace, it matches the characters within the brackets – or all characters except those in the brackets, if `^` is leading.

You should check the return value to see if `q` was actually input; this has somewhat different behavior than your code if "rest of line" is actually empty.  (Or if the line starts with whitespace.)

Comment: space in formatstring will be ignored, "%s %[^\n]" is equivalent to "%s%[^\n]"